# How to detect if an object is of type generic List and cast to the required type?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have an extension method for converting a generic list to string.

```
public static string ConvertToString<T>(this IList<T> list)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (T item in list)
    {
        sb.Append(item.ToString());
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I have an object which is of type object that holds a list; the list could be `List<string>`, `List<int>`, `List<ComplexType>` any type of list.

Is there a way that I can detect that this object is a generic list and therefore cast to that specific generic list type to call the `ConvertToString` method?

```
//ignore whats happening here
//just need to know its an object which is actually a list
object o = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

if (o is of type list)
{
    string value = (cast o to generic type).ConvertToString();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* achieve that, with lots of reflection (both to find the correct `T`, and then to invoke via `MakeGenericMethod` etc); however: you aren't ***using*** the generic features, so remove them! (or have a secondary non-generic API):

```
public static string ConvertToString(this IEnumerable list)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (object item in list)
    {
        sb.Append(item.ToString());
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

and

```
IList list = o as IList;
if (list != null)
{
    string value = list.ConvertToString();
}
```

(you can also use `IEnumerable` in the above step, but you need to be careful with `string` etc if you do that)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of coding the extension method against IList<T>, you could code it against IEnumerable, then it'd be:

```
public static string ConvertToString(this IEnumerable list)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (object item in list)
    {
        sb.Append(item.ToString());
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then you could check if `o` is an IEnumerable:

```
object o = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

if (o is IEnumerable)
{
    string value = ((IEnumerable) o).ConvertToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Type to see if your type is an arrat (IsArray) and if it's a generic type (IsGenericType)

Comment: a list is not an array; that also doesn't help the OP find the `T` or invoke the method